# Config file to change values within an app

Tags: blackberry

I'm having a problem meeting a requirement for an Java app I'm developing. My client must be able to deploy the app to multiple BES servers without the need to resign the code (or have any interaction with the developers). Currently the web address of one of their BES servers is hard coded into the app but they require the ability to change this value at will prior to deployment. (it can be assumed they will administrate any BES server the app is deployed from)

I've tried attaching a text file to the project which is read by the app but this is packaged along with the app, meaning it can't be manually edited (as far as I'm aware), I've also tried having a custom property in the JAD file but this needs resigned after any change.

Am I doing any of these approaches wrong or is there a better solution I'm missing?

Also, is it possible to deploy a simple text file to a BlackBerry via the BES to a specific file location? If so I could have my app read this file which would solve the problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [custom attachment handler](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800698/How_To_-_Create_a_custom_Attachment_Handler_on_the_BlackBerry_device.html?nodeid=800702&vernum=0) in your application.

And send email with an attached xml-config file to BlackBerry device.

User opens the received message and selects the custom menu item provided by attachment handler.

And you can parse this xml config and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to use a user defined ItPolicy to provide the configuration information you need.